# Getting a good "path" from an Android service

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am making an app that will draw a user's path on a map.   This is all working fine.   However, I also want to continue to collect the path (when requested by the user) when the app is in the background.  This also is working pretty good, but occasionally I get "glitches".   See this map for an example:

[GoogleMap](https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zWeFTl4RMS10.ksJGMKIlIeyo&usp=sharing)

I believe what is happening is that when I start the service, I am getting the "last known location" instead of the current location.  I have tried several techniques without much luck so far.  Some other ideas that I have have had:

- Passing the GoogleApiClient from the Activity to the Service, already connected (is this possible?)
- Ignoring the first "X" location updates in the service (how big does "X" need to be?)
- Cleansing the path, to remove "bad" locations (what kind of algorithm would I need to figure out what a "bad" location is...it is easy to see in the attached map, but I am not sure how to do it in code).

Any other suggestions on the best way to handle this scenario?

Here is some code to give you an idea of the current functionality:

Activity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    setUpMapIfNeeded();  
    buildGoogleApiClient();  
    createLocationRequest();
    ...
}

private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(Utils.LOCATION_UPDATE_MS);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(Utils.FASTEST_LOCATION_UPDATE_MS);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    Log.v("Connected", String.format("Location:  %f, %f, %f", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), location.getAccuracy()));
    if (location != null) {
        updateMap();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(pathReceiver);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
    if (isNavigatingTo()) {
        Preferences.save(Preferences.PREFERENCE_NAVIGATE_TO, navigateToWaypoint.getId());
    } else {
        Preferences.remove(Preferences.PREFERENCE_NAVIGATE_TO);
    }
    if(isRecordingTrack()){
        // Start the PathSevice to continue recording the track.
        Intent pathServiceIntent = new Intent(this, PathService.class);
        pathServiceIntent.putExtra(Utils.PATH_EXTRA, path);
        startService(pathServiceIntent);
    }
}
...
```

PathService.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    createLocationRequest();
    googleApiClient.connect();
    super.onCreate();
}

private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(Utils.LOCATION_UPDATE_MS);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(Utils.FASTEST_LOCATION_UPDATE_MS);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    path.addPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was in my question...as it seemed I was adding the "last known location" when returning back to the activity from the service (see onConnected in the Activity class above).

I now only start the location requests in the onConnected.